# How to Write a Script to add extra columns for my primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table in SQL Server 2008 R2

[image]

Now I need to write a script to add a new column `cusomerVLANID` as part of the primary key, so that the three columns becomes the primary key, is there a way to write such script.

Second thing I want to write a script to remove the `Allow Null`, check box from the `CustomerVLANID` columns ?

Thanks

Comment: It will help you in a large way to learn how to script these things and stop using the SSMS editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>

ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY ([ID], [CustomerName], [CustomerVLANSID])
```

Run this statement separately to set up the `NOT NULL` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
ALTER COLUMN [CustomerVLANSID] INT NOT NULL
```

Comment: can i be more specific and remove the PK directly, or i need to mention the constraint_Name first ?

Comment: not sure if i understand your question, but in order to drop a PK, you have to specify it by name.

Comment: i tried your syntax, but i got the following error "
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'"

Comment: See changes made to both statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table TABLE1
alter column [CustomerVLANID] int not null
```

I hope this helps,

-Thomas
RosSQL.blogspot.com